# Java - How to fetch all rows data from database

Tags: java, mysql, swing

i'm making simple lab management system using java swing GUI where i need to print out all patients data from database table but i cannot found how to retrieve all rows data from database. With below code i'm getting only last row data.

```
private void inner_search_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    String search = this.search_field.getText();
    String name = null;
    try{
        if(search.trim().length() == 0){
            this.results_field.setText("Please fill in search field !!!");
        }
        else
        {
            String query = "select * from lab_tests";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);



            int i =0;

            while(rs.next())
            {                   
                i++;
                name = rs.getString("patient_name");                
                this.results_field.setText("<html>" + name + "<br></html>");
            }

        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){

    }
}
```

Comment: `setText("<html>" + name + "<br></html>");` replace text

Comment: Beware of fetching *all* rows from the database.  Your UI will slow to a crawl if your table has too many rows (think thousands of records).

Comment: @Brian Only if you've done something wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are replacing text each time .that's why you are getting only final database record .use `jtextarea`instead `jtextfield` and use append method

```
textArea.append(name + "\n");
```

or you can use `stringBuilder`

Comment: Thanks for your help, is there any better way to display data instead of textarea ?

Comment: @anasnaqvi yes you need a jtable .it's the best component for that

Answer (score 0):

best would be to make a domain class, something like

```
class Patient {
 private String fName;
 private String lName;
 private int age;

 public void setfName(String s){fName=s;}
 public String getfName(){return fName;}

 public void setlName(String s){lName=s;}
 public String getlName(){return lName;}

 public void setAge(Int i){age=i;}
 public int getAger(){return age;}

}
```

and in the function where you are getting data from the data base be like:

```
public ArrayList<Patient> getPatients(){

 public ArrayList<Patient> pList= new ArrayList<Patient>();

// part where you do you query on DB

 while(rs.next())
            {                   
                Patient p = new Patient();
                p.setfName(rs.getString("patient_name"));                
                p.setlName(rs.getString(2));
                p.setAge(rs.getInt(3));
                pList.add(p);
            }

 return pList;

}
```

and then add that data to Jtable